# How can I search in a list of dict to get some key?

Tags: ansible, yaml

Im trying to search using the key NAME of "servers" on "validar". If it exist i want to display something like this:
name: server7
proc_r: 0.1
But im geeting always 0
And if it doesnt exist, search the proc executting some command. What im doing wrong?

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    servers:
      - name: server5
        pri_sys: prod2
        proc: 0.7
        sec_sys: cont2
      - name: server7
        pri_sys: prod2
        proc: 0.1
        sec_sys: cont2
      - name: server2
        pri_sys: prod1
        proc: 0.35
        sec_sys: cont1
    validar:
      - sec_sys: cont2
        name:
          - server7
          - server9
          - server11
      - sec_sys: cont1
        name:
          - server4
          - server6

  tasks:
    - name: Create list
      set_fact:
        proc_reserved: >-
          {{ 
            proc_reserved | default([])
            + [{
              'proc_r': servers
                | selectattr('name', '==', item.name)
                | map(attribute="proc")
                |float,
              'name': item.name
            }]
          }}
      loop: "{{ validar }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.name}}"

    - name: DISPLAY PROC_RESERVED
      debug:
        var: proc_reserved


    - name: Getting proc not listed on servers
      debug:
        msg: "Search proc of {{ item.name }}"
      with_items: "{{ servers }}"
      when: item.name not in server_ 
      vars:
        server_: "{{ validar | selectattr('name') }}"
```

Comment: Please don't post incomplete questions

Comment: That's yaml, not json. Please fix your tags

Comment: Although it was quite possible to get your exact expectation from the example code, this is not an [mcve](/help/mcve) and lacks (non exhaustive list) the current output you get, the error you are dealing with, your debug effort to try understanding and fixing the issue... Please think about it for a next question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following example meets your expectation although refactoring the selected servers keys looks like an overkill to me.

The solution uses `json_query` to limit/change the selected keys in your initial dict list. Please see the [requirements](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-json-data-json-queries) to run that filter.

**`play.yml`**

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    servers:
      - name: server5
        pri_sys: prod2
        proc: 0.7
        sec_sys: cont2
      - name: server7
        pri_sys: prod2
        proc: 0.1
        sec_sys: cont2
      - name: server2
        pri_sys: prod1
        proc: 0.35
        sec_sys: cont1
    validar:
      - sec_sys: cont2
        name:
          - server7
          - server9
          - server11
      - sec_sys: cont1
        name:
          - server4
          - server6
    validar_servers: "{{ validar | map(attribute='name') | flatten | unique | sort }}"
    reserved_servers: "{{ servers | selectattr('name', 'in', validar_servers) }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Display the raw calculated var (which you can use as is in loop for example)
      debug:
        var: reserved_servers

    - name: Refactor the var although this does not really seem necessary
      vars:
        query: >-
          [].{name: name, proc_r: proc}
      debug:
        msg: "{{ reserved_servers | json_query(query) }}"
```

Which gives:

```
$ ansible-playbook play.yml 

PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Display the raw calculated var (which you can use as is in loop for example)] ****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "reserved_servers": [
        {
            "name": "server7",
            "pri_sys": "prod2",
            "proc": 0.1,
            "sec_sys": "cont2"
        }
    ]
}

TASK [Refactor the var although this does not really seem necessary] *******************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "name": "server7",
            "proc_r": 0.1
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```